# How to say "one of the values of this readonly record" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this enum

```
enum MyTypes {
 TypeA = 'TypeA';
 TypeB = 'TypeB';
}
```

and with that enum, I build this record:

```
const MyRecord: Readonly<Record<MyTypes, string>> = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const
```

Now, I want to build a function that returns `'end-point-a'` or `'end-point-b'` so I can use the returned value on a switch like

```
const myEndpoint = getEndpoint();

switch(myEndpoint){
  case MyRecord.MyTypeA:
  ///
   break;
  case MyRecord.MyTypeB:
  ///
   break;
  default:
     thisFailsWithOtherStuffThanNever(myEndpoint) // This should not fail
}
```

But I can not figure out how to define "a value inside MyRecord". Is this even possible?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2AZygbwFBSagQSgF4oByfYAsgGl0oCETzHbtsBfdgYwHsQ0AF1hwASsD4AnACYAuKOICG0-gBs4AHnFTpG%20JTQ0oQyQEsQAcwB8V5jihQA2vpToAdJQIBdeWVDSAWmRec0EAxTYHZ0RXNA9XBh9yfyCQkDCAIzJOAG52ADMwEG5BU34oQQALUzQAMUVTVTQAdVMqgHkq4EkAZUEwfPyESsUQADlgADdugAoQXlR5ECnugEocLmxC4tLyi2BBAFEQaWDQmdX5E3MLLFwoSQOwSRARbV4ZeMI8zb4BYQgcGOpzSwlI%20yOJzO6QueWwaAA7m1uJUZoDgdDBOt7txFGhgG8JB9pF8qLJ7gB6Kn3BwZR6KADWeQcuPxhJ0pIY5IcVIp9zpwEZzKg0mA%20UUYFUgm5DgcVRq9UaLTalU6lW6fQGQxG4xWkjRQKhoNWnCAA)

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I added a playground link

Comment: What do you want to return ?

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGqBw). Are you looking for smth like that ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I want that typescript narrows `myEndpoint` to just the two values of `MyRecord`, so `thisFailsWithOtherStuffThanNever` not fails because in that place `myEndpoint` is `never`

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6qJw)

Comment: That is it! Can you please do it as an answer ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed yo use explicit `Readonly<...>` type with `as const`  assertion.
You need to use `satisfies` instead. This is new keyword which was introduced in [TS 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton)

```js
const MyRecord = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const satisfies Readonly<Record<MyTypes, string>>
```

Now, you have a guarantee that `MyRecord` satisfies your type and you have type inference.

Now, you need to create a type which will consist of values of `MyRecord` obj.
Let's name it `Endpoints`:

```js
enum MyTypes {
  TypeA = 'TypeA',
  TypeB = 'TypeB',

}

const MyRecord = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const satisfies Readonly<Record<MyTypes, string>>

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type EndpointMap = typeof MyRecord

type Endpoints = Values<EndpointMap>
```

The whole code:

```js
enum MyTypes {
  TypeA = 'TypeA',
  TypeB = 'TypeB',

}

const MyRecord = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const satisfies Readonly<Record<MyTypes, string>>

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type EndpointMap = typeof MyRecord

type Endpoints = Values<EndpointMap>


function thisFailsWithOtherStuffThanNever(nope: never) {
}

function getEndpoint(): Endpoints {
  return MyRecord.TypeA;
}

const myEndpoint = getEndpoint();

const foo = (endpoint: Endpoints) => {
  switch (endpoint) {
    case MyRecord.TypeA:
      ///
      break;
    case MyRecord.TypeB:
      ///
      break;
    default:
      thisFailsWithOtherStuffThanNever(endpoint)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzPG2N)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the mapping login in two places:

First place is the MyRecord

```js
const MyRecord: Readonly<Record<MyTypes, string>> = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const
```

The second one is in the swithc/case statement.

```js
const myEndpoint = getEndpoint();

switch(myEndpoint){
  ///..
}
```

You have to choose one. I'll propose two solutions to it. I prefer the first one. Playground links proived

Solution one: use that mapping object. [Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2AZygbwFBSagQSgF4oByfYAsgGl0oCETzGzsBfbbAYwHsQ0AFyigAJsl4BLEIJgBDZMmkBzAFxQASsDmj%20AGzgAeLXwBOow0NMqaUKyoB8D5jihQA2vEpoAdJQIAuupkYgC0EtKCoXK0uB5eKOh%20iQxB5GERMqEARmzsUHIYfAKCXDz8QlDKwIIAoiDiUjLMABQAlCTOrm6mNWCmIFAARP5DANwcXMWVEHD1jZHM1XUNmYLtE%20UlUBAKqKLzmcoAanJ6YMDMYmvyiirus4dNggGbkgBmUC27isAHq00TmcLlAAITEUhgBrAd7SP4dbpQaa8PTAHx6XjKFoAAwAklAABZyABul3evDAokGggJlx%20ShAyigkmEkgwABJMPS-k8VKdzsB2Ni2hwRHo0JdEQB6KVQAAScgaqOZgh8UAACqZeNk5NkDFAaVqAO4FQbAUxa0xQOJIiootHmy04gByvGEaDAil4pkEYhEAMWgkSUE5jwDMiFbQm7CAA)

```js
const endpointMapping: Readonly<Record<string, string>> = {
  [MyTypes.TypeA]: 'end-point-a',
  [MyTypes.TypeB]: 'end-point-b'
} as const

const myEndpoint = getEndpoint();

const mappedEndpoingValue = endpointMapping[myEndpoint];

if (mappedEndpoingValue !== undefined) {
   console.log(`I have foudn the mapping it is ${mappedEndpoingValue}`)
} else {
   // Handle it. Probably throw an error 
   console.error(`Not supportend endpoint type ${myEndpoint}`);
}
```

Solution two: use the switch/case statement. [Pllaygroudn using switch case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=69&pln=10&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2AZygbwFBSagQSgF4oByfYAsgGl0oCETzGzsBfbbAYwHsQ0AFygBzYIICiIACbJeASxDDSACgCUJAHxZcUKACdxYfSCgAiSgTMBuDlz4DhEOFNkKlzMZJlzFg9bbYADbiUBAAhsio0q6%20ICIAauFBYMAAXFBC%20ooizGY2XGgA7vKC3AAWUCrOse6CGjh63OFowLCIKOgAdJZpunoRUcAxPu6Jyal5oNIAtHGCM%20Fm-VAARobhANa2TS1t8JRoPZ0MfXoDkdG1OUkpbaRm03N1i8vnaxvbutLAAGbhYCCggy-QA9KCoAAJcIyEJQUpdKAABX0vFW4VWQTgUEE5VRRSgMKgwH0qP0UH6DjQvBCXRJZJUAAMAHK8YRoMBRXj6QTTYmjPw4zpQAAkmBqAqU7EZah2elx%20KgIGABIkpO5KjMIDZUF%20vDAHkGyByZjUdh4-GptKCvBETIAklByuEAG5tPVgaSmXFtI05eHCeQYMVG4bXeK3VLStRAA)

```js
const myEndpoint = getEndpoint();

let mappedEndpoingValue: string = "";

switch (myEndpoint) {
  case MyTypes.TypeA:
    mappedEndpoingValue = "end-point-a"
    break;
  case MyTypes.TypeB:
    mappedEndpoingValue = "end-point-a"
    break;
  default: 
   // Handle it. Probably throw an error 
   console.error(`Not supportend endpoint type ${myEndpoint}`);
   throw new Error("not fount mapping")
}

console.log(`I have foudn the mapping it is ${mappedEndpoingValue}`)
```